# OpenCV, JavaCV Random prediction results for the some subject

Tags: java, opencv, classification, javacv, prediction

I use JavaCV for Gender Classification.

My problem is that i have different result on each prediction for the some subject (face). So it's possible to have 2 different results for the some face!
example face 1:
first prediction -> Male
second prediction -> Female

My Question is if it's normal to receive different result on each prediction for the same subject?

Thanks.

Comment: your question is a bit fuzzy. it is indeed possible to get 2 different results for 2 different images of the *same* person. is that , what you mean ?

Comment: no it's the some image "x" scanned multiple times, but results are different on each scan ..

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the same input you should receive always the same output!

If you have an image of a person, you should always get the same result. But if your input is for example a live video from a webcam, it's normal that your classification makes errors depending on the Inputquality.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Schmitz for your response,

Comment: Well pretty much by definition of how programs work you must have another source of input that changes the outcome. Unfortunately i don't have a better advice for you than that you have to debug your program. Try for example to make a minimal working example, you could post that here as well if you need more help.